# How to set child item properties in Silverlight using XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles

I've got a Grid in my XAML page. The grid is simply a holder for XAML loaded from the database:

```
<Grid x:Name="dynamicXamlHolder" />
```

**I want all `<TextBlock>` objects that get inserted into that grid to have `.TextWrapping = Wrap`.**

How can I do this? I'm sensing styles might be the answer, but it's unclear to me how to create a grid style that affects `<TextBlock>` elements in the grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
```